# Firebase authentication issue - An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have used Firebase authentication to receive an OTP for the verification of the user. For that, I have used following method,

```
        PhoneAuthProvider.provider().verifyPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, uiDelegate: nil) { (verificationID, error) in
      if let error = error {
        showAlert(error.localizedDescription)
        return
      }

      print(verificationID)
    }
```

Now, the issue is whenever we test release build from test flight in our devices, we are successfully authenticated but when we submit same build for the review team of Apple, they are facing following error,

> An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information.

Kindly help me how to regenerate above issue from my side, and solve it.

Comment: did you find the problem ?

Comment: Hi, did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Check authentication OTP service enabled for other region or not in firebase.

Comment: We have given them testing phone number of India only and same phone number they are using.

Comment: That was the correct answer for me. Thank you!

Comment: are you talking about this: https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/admin/sms-regions?hl=en&authuser=0

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too,
and this issue is related to  GoogleService-Info.plist. after changing it
this issue became solved.

Comment: Please suggest the changes, I'm facing same issue